# Characters Missing

Tags: c#, binary

I'm trying to send a JSON request to a remote device that then returns a JSON response.

The code I've used is this:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("someip"), someport);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] myWriteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some JSON");
stream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length);
BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(stream);
Console.WriteLine(r.ReadString())
```

This code successfully sends the JSON string, receives the response, but that response only shows 123 characters, meaning that it cuts some chars...

What am I doing wrong

Comment: What does the response look like? At which character is it being cut?

Comment: well, what is the response? where does it break? is this perhaps just a whitespace / carriage return issue? i.e. is the remote device returning JSON with a line-break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an encoding/decoding issue, I would change your code like so

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("someip"), someport);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] myWriteBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some JSON");
stream.Write(myWriteBuffer, 0, myWriteBuffer.Length);

byte[] readBuffer = stream.GetBuffer();
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
```

Comment: GetBuffer() only exists for `MemoryStream`; this is a `NetworkStream`. **at a minumum** you'd need successive `Read` calls to get the correct data

Answer (score 4):

`BinaryReader` / `BinaryWriter` are not necessarily the right tools for writing to an arbitrary stream; in particular, they choose a specific way of encoding strings, with a length-prefix. If this is not what your remote device is expecting, it will fail.

I would just use the `Stream` directly, with `Read` and `Write`.

In particular, `{` is 123 in ASCII, so it looks `BinaryReader` is incorrectly taking the "length" from the opening JSON brace.